# Environment variable are undefined inside the child/imported file in node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, es6-modules, dotenv

I am using **dotenv** package in my node/express project.

I have an root/index file where I am **importing** different files.

I imported dotenv in index file only. There within index file environment variable are accessible but in the imported file these are not accessible.
How can I make it accessible inside other file imported inside indes.js?

Here's a glimpse of my code

index.js

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import { sync, getImages, downloadImage } from "./api/controllers/shutterstock";
console.log(process.env.SHUTTERSTOCK_ACCESS_TOKEN); //===>Working gives me the access token
```

api/controllers/shutterstock.js

```
console.log(process.env.SHUTTERSTOCK_ACCESS_TOKEN); //===>undefined
```

This is how my directory structure looks like
[image]

Comment: do you have an "env" file in the root of your project? Your environment variables should go there.

Comment: Yes .env is there in the root, That's why it is working inside the index file

Answer (score 6):

Your *index.js* is `import`ing the *api/controllers/shutterstock.js*, and imports are "hoisted" (all dependencies are evaluated before starting the execution of the importing module), which causes the `console.log` in the latter to be evaluated **before** `dotenv.config()` is executed and has loaded the `.env` file.

You can work around this in several ways:

- don't immediately access `process.env` in the top-level module scope in *shutterstock.js*, but e.g. only inside the `downloadImage` function. If you call `downloadImage()` after the `dotenv.config()`, it'll work.
- defer the loading of *shutterstock.js* until after dotenv got initialised:

  ```
  import dotenv from "dotenv";
  dotenv.config();
  const { sync, getImages, downloadImage } = await import("./api/controllers/shutterstock");
  ```
- import a module that does the `dotenv.config()` call before the *shutterstock.js* module - dependencies are loaded and evaluated in order. [Dotenv comes with such a module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#preload) already:

  ```
  import "dotenv/config";
  import { sync, getImages, downloadImage } from "./api/controllers/shutterstock";
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution form this comment: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/133#issuecomment-255298822

Move the dotenv call into a separate file and then import it in index.js.

```
// index.js
import _ from './env'
import hello from './hello'
```

```
// env.js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ silent: true })
```

It is also recommended from the library
`Create a separate file that will execute config first as outlined in this comment on #133` https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

import { default as dotenv } from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });
This worked for me when other solutions did not, tried the seperate file import, and everything else in this thread, https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/133
Also tried other stack articles, this one did the trick with a standard node setup with es6 style imports.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your require('dotenv').config() is placed above all the file imports inside of index.js file. Basically, sequence of imports (require)